# jQuery/JS function to work only when a button is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, toggle

I've made jQuery function like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#mmenu").hide();
    $("#cover").hide();
    var wys = $('#mmenu').height();
    console.log('wys: ' + wys);
    $(".mtoggle").click(function () {
        $("#mmenu").slideToggle(500);
        $("#cover").fadeToggle("400", "swing");
        $(window).scroll(function (e) {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > wys) {
                var limit = wys + 50;
                $(window).scrollTop(limit);
            }
        });

        $(window).scrollTop(wys);

    });
});
```

It toggles sliding of a menu `#mmenu`, fades in or out the `#cover div`, which darkens the whole area behind the menu and disables scrolling at a certain point. The problem is i want the scrollTop function to work only when menu is open (when the button is clicked) and to stop work if the menu is hidden again. For now, it starts to work when i open the menu, but when i close it the scrolling stays disabled. How do i make this function working only when the menu is open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly then you need to register/remove the scroll handler based on whether the menu is opened/closed.

One easy solution is to use a flag as shown below

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#mmenu").hide();
    $("#cover").hide();
    var wys = $('#mmenu').height();

    //flag to keep track of open status
    var open = false;

    console.log('wys: ' + wys);
    $(".mtoggle").click(function () {
        $("#mmenu").slideToggle(500);
        $("#cover").fadeToggle("400", "swing");

        //if already opened then remove the handler
        if (open) {
            $(window).off('scroll.menuopen');
        } else {
            //if opening now then register the handler
            $(window).on('scroll.menuopen', scrollHandler);
            $(window).scrollTop(wys);
        }
        //toggle the open status
        open = !open;
    });

    function scrollHandler(e) {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > wys) {
            var limit = wys + 50;
            $(window).scrollTop(limit);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check whether the menu is `:visible`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#mmenu").hide();
    $("#cover").hide();
    var wys = $('#mmenu').height();
    console.log('wys: ' + wys);
    $(".mtoggle").click(function () {
        $("#mmenu").slideToggle(500);
        $("#cover").fadeToggle("400", "swing");
        if($("#mmenu").is(':visible')){ //BEGIN - Check whether the menu is visible
            $(window).scroll(function (e) {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > wys) {
                    var limit = wys + 50;
                    $(window).scrollTop(limit);
                }
            });
            $(window).scrollTop(wys);
        } //END


    });
});
```